# innerHTML works only once in my react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

What I am trying to do is clear my container div when the user hits the search button so all the existing search results are removed.
The problem is I  am using innerHTML to clear the container div but it only works for the first time.
If you search for something for the second time then you will see no results are rendered.
I've just started learning reactjs.
Here is my code (I have removed the API key and the id just FYI).

```
import React from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import "./styles.css";



export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: "Icecream",
      searchData: [],
      error: false,
      loader: false
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector(".control.field").classList.add("is-loading");

    this.setState({
      error: false,
      loader: true
    });

    document.querySelector(".columns").innerHTML = "test";

    fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${
        this.state.searchQuery
      }&app_id=id&app_key=key`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          searchData: data.hits
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          error: true
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        document.querySelector(".control.field").classList.remove("is-loading");
        this.setState({
          loader: false
        });
      });
  }

  renderIngredients = arr => arr.map((el, index) => <li key={index}>{el}</li>);

  render() {
    let result;

    result = this.state.searchData.map((el, index) => (
      <Recipe
        key={index}
        image={el.recipe.image}
        title={el.recipe.label}
        ingredients={this.renderIngredients(el.recipe.ingredientLines)}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <form className="px-3 py-3" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="field is-grouped">
            <p className="control field is-expanded">
              <input
                className="input is-rounded"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Find a recipe"
                name="searchQuery"
                value={this.state.searchQuery}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </p>
            <p className="control">
              <button className="button is-primary">Search</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
        {this.state.loader ? (
          <div className="spinner-box">
            <div className="three-quarter-spinner" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {this.state.error ? (
          <div className="px-3 py-3">
            <div className="notification is-danger">
              Some error occured. Unable to fetch
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="columns is-multiline px-3 py-3 is-mobile">
            {result}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Recipe component :

```
import React from "react";

export default class Recipe extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="column is-one-quarter-desktop is-half-mobile">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image">
            <figure className="image is-4by3">
              <img src={this.props.image} alt="" />
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <p className="title is-6">{this.props.title}</p>
            <ul>{this.props.ingredients}</ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In React if you want to access DOM elements, you use refs. Read about them. I don't know if that's causing your problem, but you should use ref anyway.

Comment: There is NO reason to be using DOM methods in react. Do it the react way. You should not be adding removing classes with DOM, you should not be setting html with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using new `state` for that?
What I mean is that:

```
this.state = {
 ...,
 focusSearch: false
}

const handleFocus = () => {
   this.setState({ ...this.state, focusSearch: true});
}


<input
                className="input is-rounded"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Find a recipe"
                name="searchQuery"
                value={this.state.searchQuery}
                onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />


render() {
 return (
  {
 focusSearch ? <div></div> : <></>;
}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this morning. It can be done easily using conditional rending and ternary operator.
Thank you, everyone.